# Mongodb - Does projection increase the execution time?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Lets say I have 50 fields in my document.

When I use projection, and just select 4 fields, does my execution time increase or decrease?

How does mongodb handle it?

1. Does mongodb fetch the document, then filter the fields and return?
2. Does mongodb fetch the selected fields instead of the whole document and return?
3. Does it work different for `find` and `aggregate`?

I believe 1st option will increase the execution time, while 2nd option will decrease it.

Answer (score 0):

well it all depends I guess... depends what your search criteria are.  It can only be point 1 in my opinion (or it should be heavily optimized), since any filtering or aggregation or whatever can be on fields that aren't in the projection.  and btw.... define 'fetch'.  fetch to the client, i would say no, 'fetched' on the server yes.  In general I would say that, if your queries are not that complex, even if projection takes some additional time, it will balans with the total time in transmitting the data to the client.  All in all we are talking milliseconds here and overall transmission times and delays are harder to surpress than optimizing DB queries.

In addition, I have found the following (More technical than my opinion): https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198444/how-mongodb-projection-affects-performance

Comment: Well the example is just about a single document. But when its 1000+ docs, and you are using lambda functions, and you are getting huge number of calls, those milliseconds matter.

Comment: By Fetch, I mean the Fetch stage of mongodb, where it will retrieve the document, and load into its memory.

Comment: yes valid points / agreed, but as with everything you can build a correct setup, but you can also build the same setup poorly (wrong/no indexes, no password on public Internet:), . difficult to say (anything can be done wrong).   As said, I think the attached link gives a more technical approach on how you can benefit with projection and in which cases